# Is there way to change the value of a variable in a python script from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a python script and apache web server running in a raspberry pi. I want to change the value of a variable in my python script from a web page using javascript. It is possible?

Comment: you can't directly change it. JavaScript would have to use AJAX to send request with data to server, server would have to receive this data and use it to change file or rather it would have to use this value when it runs script. Normally HTML has `<form>` to send data to server and server uses this data to generate new page.

Comment: What do you mean "change a variable in my python script" ? A "python script" is a text file, not a running process.

Answer (score 0):

We can use socket.  for easily using socket, we can use socket.io

**Start.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Socket.IO GPIO control</h1>
    <button id="btnGpio">Change GPIO</button>

    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
        var index = 0;
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('connected')

            document.getElementById('btnGpio').addEventListener('click', () => {
                index = index + 1;
                console.log('index', index)
                socket.emit('change_gpio', { status: (index % 2 == 0) })
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**socket_server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("Start.html")

socketio = SocketIO(app)

pin = True
@socketio.on('change_gpio')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    pin = json['status']
    print('pin = ' , pin)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/')
def test_connect():
    print('Connected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Install library with pip

```
pip install flask
pip install flask-socketio
```

**Document:**
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/